# How to make valueLink of react work with select elements?

Tags: html, reactjs

I've read about both [react forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) and [react two way binding helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html). 
But I can't find any saying about how to implement two-way bindings with `select` elements.

I've tried like:

```
render: {
  var selectValueLink = {
    value: this.state.selectedValue,
    requestChange: this.handleChange
  };

  return (
    <select valueLink={selectValueLink}>
      <option value={'A'}>OPTION A</option>
      <option value={'B'}>OPTION B</option>
      <option value={'C'}>OPTION C</option>      
    </select>
  );
}
```

but `this.handleChange` doesn't get fired when I manually change selected options via mouse clicks.

Is there any way to use React's `valueLink` nicely with select elements?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with select element and everything seems to be working http://plnkr.co/edit/3ueB63nxJ4wwV8rSIusr.

Comment: also, consider using `LinkedStateMixin` so you don't have to construct valueLink objects yourself.  `<select valueLink={this.linkState("whateverKeyWillHoldYourState")}>`